# SQL query resultset, I need SUM(quantity) COLUMN grouped by DAY

Tags: sql, count, sum, having

This is the Query I am using on the `product` table `LEFT JOIN` on the `page` table `ON` the `productid` column in `page` being the `id` in `product`.. pretty straightforward.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT `p`.`id`) as `quantity`,
DATE_FORMAT(`p`.`created_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `day`
FROM
`product` AS `p` 
LEFT JOIN
`page` AS `pg` ON `p`.`id` = `pg`.`productid` 
WHERE
`p`.`created_time` BETWEEN '2013-07-03 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-10 23:59:59'
AND
`p`.`group` = '101' 
GROUP BY `day`, `p`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`pg`.`productid`)>=10 
ORDER BY `p`.`created_time`
```

The two example tables concerned:

```
**product**
id  created_time
32  2013-07-09
33  2013-07-09

**page**
id  productid
1   33
2   33
..  ..
20  33
21  32
22  32
..  ..
54  32
```

Now my resultset looks like this:

```
quantity    day
1           2013-07-09
1           2013-07-09
1           2013-07-10
```

But I would like the following output without `UNION` and without using `temp` tables:

```
quantity    day
2           2013-07-09
1           2013-07-10
```

Two tables are now added to my code example on top. I need the number of `product` with ten or more `page` grouped by `day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(`p`.`id`) as `quantity`,
DATE_FORMAT(`p`.`created_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `day`
FROM
`product` AS `p`
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
    `productid` AS `id`,
    count(id) AS pagesNR 
FROM 
    `page`
GROUP BY 
    `productid` HAVING COUNT(`id`) >= 10
)
AS 
`pg` USING (`id`)
WHERE
    `p`.`created_time` BETWEEN '2013-07-03 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-10 23:59:59'
AND
    `p`.`group` = '101'
GROUP BY 
    `day`
ORDER BY 
    `created_time`
```

Thanks to a friend of my co-worker Daniël Versteeg

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because you are leaving `p.id` in the `group by` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `p`.`id`) as `quantity`,
       DATE_FORMAT(`p`.`created_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `day`
FROM `product` AS `p` LEFT JOIN
     `page` AS `pg`
      ON `p`.`id` = `pg`.`productid` 
WHERE `p`.`created_time` BETWEEN '2013-07-03 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-10 23:59:59'
      AND `p`.`group` = '101' 
GROUP BY `day`
HAVING COUNT(`pg`.`productid`)>=10 
ORDER BY `p`.`created_time`
```

Comment: Very close guys, but I need the sum of the quantity having 10 or more pages.. in your answers the resultset includes the product with less than 10 pages also.

Comment: Thank you for the effort @MaxiWheat and Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

Don't `GROUP BY` the `id` value and also the `ORDER BY` can be on `day` too

Note that `day` is not available in the `GROUP BY` in standard SQL or when [`sql_mode` is using `"only_full_group_by"`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). MySQL allows it as an extension but it is misleading

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as `quantity`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`p`.`created_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `day`
FROM
   `product` AS `p` 
   JOIN
   `page` AS `pg` ON `p`.`id` = `pg`.`productid` 
WHERE
   `p`.`created_time` BETWEEN '2013-07-03 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-10 23:59:59'
   AND
   `p`.`group` = '101' 
GROUP BY
   `pg`.`productid`, DATE_FORMAT(`p`.`created_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `day`
HAVING
   COUNT(*) >= 10 
ORDER BY
   `day`;
```

Comment: Very close guys(), but I need the sum of the quantity having 10 or more pages.. in your answers the resultset includes the product with less than 10 pages also.

Comment: @Theo: fixed the JOIN and COUNT to match your requirements

Comment: my query only returns a row `HAVING` 10 or more page of the same product and your solution solves the total of the day instead per product.

Comment: @Theo: add more data to the question then. We're guessing here. As per my latest update: per product, per day, more than 10 rows in the page table

Comment: Ok I agree, not enough information given.. I am going to add the two example tables. And again, I need the number of `product` per `day` with more than 10 `page` records.

Comment: Two tables are now added to my code example on top. I need the number of `product` with ten or more `page` grouped by `day`

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort @gbn I found the answer, but upvoted your answer because it is correct as far as the information  was incomplete for the definite solution.